# Compare 2 json arrays by specific key then build new json array containing all and include missing key values but manually set the value

Tags: javascript

I have 2 JSON arrays which I want to compare the smaller one with the bigger one to see which date is missing from the smaller one. I then want to write a new JSON array by using the existing values of the smaller one but then adding the missing dates and setting other values manually.

Example:

This is the smaller JSON array

```
[{
    "is_mobile": "t",
    "total_recordings": "845",
    "date": "2019-03-18"
}, {
    "is_mobile": "t",
    "total_recordings": "25",
    "date": "2019-03-21"
}, {
    "is_mobile": "t",
    "total_recordings": "235",
    "date": "2019-03-22"
}]
```

This is the bigger JSON array

```
[{
    "is_mobile": "f",
    "total_recordings": "12345",
    "date": "2019-03-17"
}, {
    "is_mobile": "f",
    "total_recordings": "34343",
    "date": "2019-03-18"
}, {
    "is_mobile": "f",
    "total_recordings": "234335",
    "date": "2019-03-19"
},{
    "is_mobile": "f",
    "total_recordings": "554544",
    "date": "2019-03-20"
}, {
    "is_mobile": "f",
    "total_recordings": "777676",
    "date": "2019-03-21"
}, {
    "is_mobile": "f",
    "total_recordings": "121212",
    "date": "2019-03-22"
}]
```

I want to compare the date values to see which is missing in the smaller one by comparing it to the bigger one.

Then write a new JSON array containing all the values of the smaller one and including only the missing dates from the bigger one but manually setting the other values of the missing ones to what I define.

So the end result should have a new array like this

```
[{
    "is_mobile": "t",
    "total_recordings": "0",
    "date": "2019-03-17"
},{
    "is_mobile": "t",
    "total_recordings": "845",
    "date": "2019-03-18"
},{
    "is_mobile": "t",
    "total_recordings": "0",
    "date": "2019-03-19"
},{
    "is_mobile": "t",
    "total_recordings": "0",
    "date": "2019-03-20"
}, {
    "is_mobile": "t",
    "total_recordings": "25",
    "date": "2019-03-21"
}, {
    "is_mobile": "t",
    "total_recordings": "235",
    "date": "2019-03-22"
}]
```

As you can see the end result is that "is_mobile" is the value of the smaller array and "total_recordings" is manually set to 0 if it was one of the missing ones from the bigger array and all the rest stays as it was before.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: are you comparing by date..

Comment: My attempts to solve were by checking the tons of options on this site already of which none worked. 

Yes comparing by date

Comment: @Gobemeister check my answer

Comment: btw, [JSON](https://json.org/) is a string. what you have is an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can do using array function

```
var smaller = [{
"is_mobile": "t",
"total_recordings": "845",
"date": "2019-03-18"
}, {
"is_mobile": "t",
"total_recordings": "25",
"date": "2019-03-21"
}, {
"is_mobile": "t",
"total_recordings": "235",
"date": "2019-03-22"
}];

var bigger = [{
"is_mobile": "f",
"total_recordings": "12345",
"date": "2019-03-17"
}, {
"is_mobile": "f",
"total_recordings": "34343",
"date": "2019-03-18"
}, {
"is_mobile": "f",
"total_recordings": "234335",
"date": "2019-03-19"
},{
"is_mobile": "f",
"total_recordings": "554544",
"date": "2019-03-20"
}, {
"is_mobile": "f",
"total_recordings": "777676",
"date": "2019-03-21"
}, {
"is_mobile": "f",
"total_recordings": "121212",
"date": "2019-03-22"
}]

var newArray = [];
var dummyData = {};
 bigger.forEach((big) => {
    var index = smaller.findIndex(sml => sml.date == big.date);
    if(index != -1) {
        newArray.push(smaller[index]);
    } else {
      dummyData.is_mobile ='t';
      dummyData.total_recordings = "0";
      dummyData.date = big.date;
      newArray.push(dummyData);
       dummyData = {};
    }
 });

    console.log(JSON.stringify(newArray));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/43rbwopg/1/

Comment: Thanks for the attempt but it doesnt work right. There are duplicate dates now, run it in the console and see...dates must be unique

Comment: In this `dummyData` need to change as `null`

Answer (score 0):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for the known data, a pattern for the empty object and map the source array by taking the date for getting the object from the known data.

```js
var data = [{ is_mobile: "t", total_recordings: "845", date: "2019-03-18" }, { is_mobile: "t", total_recordings: "25", date: "2019-03-21" }, { is_mobile: "t", total_recordings: "235", date: "2019-03-22" }],
    source = [{ is_mobile: "f", total_recordings: "12345", date: "2019-03-17" }, { is_mobile: "f", total_recordings: "34343", date: "2019-03-18" }, { is_mobile: "f", total_recordings: "234335", date: "2019-03-19" }, { is_mobile: "f", total_recordings: "554544", date: "2019-03-20" }, { is_mobile: "f", total_recordings: "777676", date: "2019-03-21" }, { is_mobile: "f", total_recordings: "121212", date: "2019-03-22" }],
    pattern = { is_mobile: "t", total_recordings: "0", date: "" },
    map = new Map(data.map(o => [o.date, o])),
    result = source.map(({ date }) => Object.assign({}, pattern, { date }, map.get(date)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```